# jqueryUI spinner images missing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

I have an input element

```
<input id="spinner" value="0">
```

which I turn into the spinner on document ready

```
$("#spinner").spinner({ step: 100, min: 0 });
```

but its display is incomplete as the pic shows

[image]

and the console erros I am getting are

[image]

is it jquery's or jqueryui's fault? it used to be fine without any errors a few weeks ago.

Comment: Are you sure those images exist?

Comment: I have no idea what these images are. I only added the jqueryui css and js files to my project, nothing else.

Comment: OK, did you update JQuery UI recently? Can you find the images somewhere, maybe on another level?

Comment: Probably yes. I managed to solve as I say in a comment below, but I did not have to do this previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you want to use these components you should import the jQuery UI package (or just what you need.. in your case **images** folder).

Download it from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/). It contains the images you require, as well

Comment: that's what I did. how do I use it in my application? I added the css and js files. Now, to fix the issue I added an images folder and placed inside the missing png file. But is this standard procedure?

Comment: well this is an asp.net application. I usually have 2 folders, one for css and another for js. For all my plugins I have only used those 2 types of files, and I am pretty sure this was working earlier without me having to do this extra addition now.

Comment: @KonstantinosPapakonstantinou maybe you used an external reference to jquery ui CSS ? like this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css ? because if you use external resources won't be required to import images and all that stuff in your projects, but i won't raccomend do to that

Comment: You are correct pumpkin. I was asked to remove my cdnjs references and add the files locally. It was so much nicer like that.

Comment: @KonstantinosPapakonstantinou actually it is quite a standard procedure to store files locally, for [many reasons](http://www.elxis.org/blog/external-js-files.html). What if your cdnjs reference site is not available for some reason? in that case your website won't work too